# DX CLI - Plugin Install vs. Plugin Link

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I'm able to install a custom plugin globally via **npm i -g @somescope/myplugin** then change into the directory where the package is globally installed and can run **sfdx plugins:link** and all my custom commands are available.

However, I'm not able to use it when installing it from an internal private registry via **sfdx plugins:install @somescope/myplugin**.

Other custom plugins out on the public GitHub seem to work with doing a global npm install without a link step. See mo-dx, shane-sfdx-plugins, and many others.

What does the sfdx install approach do underneath to associate the plugin with DX that doesn't happen when doing a global npm install?

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue logged for this on the repo [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/410)

You can workaround for now by using the GitHub URL and using below

```
sfdx plugins:install https://github.com/someuser/someplugin
```

I am assuming you have a private git repo

Comment: Thank you Mohith, yes I have a private repo, was not aware there was a known issue. Much appreciated.